# Pass matchers and values using Mockito using scala

Tags: scala, mockito

I have the following code in my test...

```
val list : List[MyClass] = List(new MyClass)
...
doNothing().when(localLib).handleDelete(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), eq(list))
```

This throws the following compile exception

```
Error:(890, 83) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: java.util.List[my.package.MyClass]
    doNothing().when(localLib).handleDelete(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), eq(list))
                                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 5):

You must be using `scalatest`? There is a conflict with `Mockito`, one of the `*Spec` traits defines its own `eq`, and you end up referencing that instead of `Mockito` matcher.

Try adding an explicit import: `import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.{ eq => mockitoEq }`
and then use `mockitoEq` instead of `eq` when you need the matcher.

Answer (score 0):

`eq(list)` is indeed boolean, check signature. You should mock the last one argument:

```
doNothing().when(localLib)
  .handleDelete(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), any[List[MyClass]])
```